# Django REST endpoint for list of objects

Tags: django, architecture, django-rest-framework

I have a Django application which under `/api/v1/crm/ticket` can create tickets via a POST call. Now I want to be able to send different types of tickets (more then the one in the example code) to the same endpoint having a "dynamic" serializer depending on the data send. The endpoint should select the right "model" depending on the data properties existing in the request data.

I tried Django `db.models` but did not get them to work as I write the tickets to another external system and just pass them through, so no database table is existing and the model lacks the necessary primary key.

Can you help me out how to add more ticket types having the same endpoint?

### Code

```
class TicketAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TicketSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


class TicketSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=2048)
    type = serializers.ChoiceField(TICKET_TYPES)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        if validated_data['type'] == 'normal':
            ticket = TicketPOJO(
                validated_data['title'],
                validated_data['description'],
            )

            ...
        else:
            raise Exception('Ticket type not supported')

        return ticket
```

### Files

```
/my-cool-app
 /apps
  /crm
   /api
    /v1
     /serializers
      serializers.py
     __init.py
     urls.py
     views.py
   /clients
    /ticket
     provider.py
    /user
     provider.py
  /search
 /config
```

Comment: This mean you want with different `validated_data['type']`, will use different `class TicketSerializer` and save it in diffrent table database?

Comment: So you want to basically pass the validated data through to the external system using the same serializer and the same `TicketPOJO` class, no matter what the `type` of the data is? How will the data be passed on to the external system? Do you just serialize the `TicketPOJO`?

Comment: I would love a generic view and serialiser detecting a given set of "types" and similar to models but with validation.

Comment: Can you make the question clearer? What do you want and what exactly is missing or preventing you from achieving it? I have tried reading it a couple of times but still can't get the question

Comment: I tried to make it clearer and updated the question, now easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your models are different for each of your ticket type, I would suggest you create an individual serializer that validates them for each different model with one generic view.

You can override the `get_serializer` method in your `view` to select an appropriate `serializer` depending upon the type of ticket. Something like this

```
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Return the serializer instance that should be used for validating and
        deserializing input, and for serializing output.
        """
        type = self.request.data.get("type", '')
        if type === 'normal':
            return NormalTicketSerializer(*args, **kwargs)
        elif type == 'abnormal':
            return AbnormalTicketSerializer(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise ParseError(detail='Ticket type not supported') # This will return bad request response with status code 400.
```

Hope this helps.